# Facebook ads images appear pixelated

Tags: image, facebook, ads, blurry

I post several images in a carousel on Facebook,  each one with a small title.  Jpg or png at minimum 600px height.

The photos appear fine when i post,  but when i boost them,  they appear very bad,  low quality and barely understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error too, right now. We're trying to scale down the images below 1Mb